# Browser tab close event in android browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Is there any way **onbeforeunload** event works, when we close any tab in android browser.

It is working fine in desktop browsers.

Basically in android browser i need 
"Leave this page" or "stay on this page" pop up in all devices.

Or Is it possible or not ??

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and found solution, Below code is working for me, I thought I should share solution which works for me. I hope it would help other.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {  $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't support `onbeforeunload`, instead opting for `onunload`. This should work on desktop and mobile:

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
});
```